# Smartest way for making a sequence of characters in R

Tags: r, character, sequence

I am going to make the below sequence in R:

A A B B B A A B B B

I have used the below code:

```
rep(c("A","A","B","B","B"),2)
```

I got the correct answer as follows:

```
[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```

But I don't like my code. I would like to see the smartest way for making the above sequence. I don't know if it is possible to make the above sequence using `LETTERS[1:2]`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without using `rep` at all:

```r
LETTERS[(0:9 %% 5 > 1) + 1]
 [1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```

Here you just replace `9` with however long you want the sequence to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rep` twice :

```
rep(rep(LETTERS[1:2], c(2, 3)), 2)
#[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the above sequence using just one rep? @RonakShah

Comment: I wish `rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2:3, each = 2)` worked but it doesn't. :/

Answer (score 2):

A `Reduce()` version of @RonakShah's answer.

```
Reduce(rep, list(c(2, 3), 2), LETTERS[1:2])

# [1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variant using `rep` and `LETTERS`:

```
LETTERS[rep(rep(1:2, 2:3), 2)]
# [1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `replicate`

```
unlist(replicate(2, Map(rep, LETTERS[1:2], c(2, 3))))
#[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```